# php mysql limit unexpectet 'o' json

Tags: php, mysql, json

Im trying to receive my JSONArray with a Limit. 
For example I got 75 values in my Table and I want to show in the first page 50 and in the next page the rest 25. If i send the value page 2 it gives an unexpectet 'o' error. If i got 100 it works.

```
<?php 

 //Getting the page number which is to be displayed  
 $page = $_['page']; 

 //Initially we show the data from 1st row that means the 0th row 
 $start = 0; 

 //Limit is 3 that means we will show 3 items at once
 $limit = 3; 

 //Importing the database connection 
 require_once("dbconnect.php");

 //Counting the total item available in the database 
 $total = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id from beichten"));

 //We can go atmost to page number total/limit
 $page_limit = $total/$limit; 

 //If the page number is more than the limit we cannot show anything 
 if($page<=$page_limit){

 //Calculating start for every given page number 
 $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 

 //SQL query to fetch data of a range 
 $sql = "SELECT * from beichten limit $start, $limit";

 //Getting result 
 $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql); 

 //Adding results to an array 
 $res = array(); 

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $res[] = $row;

 }
 //Displaying the array in json format 
 echo json_encode($res);

 }else{

    echo "over";

 }

header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Comment: Ouch. Counting of the rows should be done by a count(*) ...

Comment: Then you send the content first and the header after. Another ouch. Where do you get the error?

Comment: Look at rule 44, where does that else belong? I think your else is lost...